# html5 <time> tag support

Tags: html

Is html5 `<time>` tag well supported by browsers? (What browsers)
Any Javascript function to convert "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss" format to date object?

```
<time id="tt" datetime="2012-03-04T15:06:17Z">The time</time>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var tt = document.getElementById("tt");
    var d = tt.datatime;  //This is undefined
    var s = tt.getAttribute("datetime"); //ok, return string
};
```

Comment: var d = tt.datatime; Note that you typed data instead of date - is that the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic) for a browser support table. You can use the following constructor to get a `Date` object:

```
new Date(dateString)
```

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/3RszX/) fiddle which converts a string to date and back.

Comment: Opera supports the `valueAsDate` property for `time` elements, which provides a convenient way to get a corresponding Date object.  At least one website (http://html5test.com/) seems to require that behavior when testing for browser support, but I can't find that requirement in the latest version of the spec, so perhaps it was dropped.

Comment: Okay, just found what looks to be the latest version of the spec (http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element) - it specifies a (much less useful) `dateTime` property, and Firefox 20 doesn't appear to support that either, so I'm calling that browser support table into question.  Also, I looked at the JS for html5test.com, and it appears I was wrong - it doesn't require any particular behavior, it just checks if the browser thinks it recognizes the element.

Answer (score 1):

According to [W3Schools: time tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_time.asp) page, no major browser supports the `time` tag.

Use the follow Javascript to parse date strings. See [W3Schools: Date Object](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) page

```
new Date(dateString)
```

Comment: w3schools says [a lot of things](http://w3fools.com/)... Note that w3schools is not affiliated with W3C.