# How can i use JQuery to update how long it's been since an event happened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime

I want to update the status of a request by resetting the time it's been since it was made.

For example, updating this time element to the current's time and date and express in terms of how long it's been since updated.

```
<time class="timesince" datetime="2012-06-28T02:47:40Z">June 28, 2012</time>
```

So far this is what i've come up with:

```
var date= new Date();
date.toISOString();
$("time.timesince").replaceWith(date);
$("time.timesince").timesince();
```

Where timesince is a jQuery plugin that takes a ISO 8601-formatted timestamps and returns the time it's been since the timestamp passed in.

My problem is i don't know how to access the datetime value of the time tag. How can i do that?

Comment: You're using jQuery so you can easily access that value as `$('time.timesince').attr('datetime');`

Comment: this solution wasn't hard to find in a search http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860195/html5-time-tag-support. Just beware will need a shim to support older browsers that don't hav time tag support